# Solving mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

**Part 1**:

**Software**: Mysql workbench

**Objective**: To find the 2nd match for a particular user

**Table**: Profile_match

**Columns**: a_profile_id, b_profile_id, a_profile_match_available_on, b_profile_match_available_on

**My process**:

1. Find all the matches for a particular user
2. Find all the dates of the match for that user
3. Find the 2nd match (id, date) for that user

**My Queries**:

```
select * from profile_match
where (a_profile_id = '*****' and a_profile_match_available_on is not null)
or (b_profile_id = '*****' and b_profile_match_available_on is not null)
order by a_profile_match_available_on asc limit 1,1;
```

**Complication**:

1. A particular user can be either under a_profile_id or b_profile_id, so the date he is match can be a_profile_match_available_on or b_profile_match_available_on
2. The 'order by' doesn't help as the required date can be either on a_profile_match_available_on or b_profile_match_available_on

As seen in the photo (after export to excel), the highlighted profile id is the user I am looking at, and the highlighted dates are the day the user receive the match.
[image]

**Desired outcome**:

Outcome 1: Maybe can create a new column containing all the id of people matched with that user (non-highlighted id) and another column containing the all the highlight dates

Outcome 2: Maybe just have 4 columns. 1 column is id of user, 1 column is id of the user match, 1 column is date user is match, 1 column is date where user's match is match

~~~~**Illustrated by User Dharmesh Patel**~~~~: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de87d/4)

The 2nd problem is that this query is only for a particular user. How do I expand this such that I can find the 2nd match for all my users?

**Part 2**:

**Objective**: 
To find the 2nd mutual like for all users

**Current progress**: I can find the 2nd mutual like for a particular user, but my query can't do it for all my user

Query:

```
select * from profile_match
where (a_profile_id = '*****'
or b_profile_id = '*****')
and (a_profile_match_status = 1 and b_profile_match_status = 1)
order by created_on asc limit 1,1;
```

Info: *a_profile_match_status* and *b_profile_match_status* only takes value of 0 or 1. When both is 1, it means both users like each other. Created_on is simply the date both users indicate like.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Looks like an exam question.

Comment: How do you pronounce 2st?

Comment: @Shawn in Part1 you say the id with the last date is the 2nd id but I can't find in which table the column date contains.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho, Hi! I am sorry, I don't really get what are you saying :( Which part of part 1 are you referring to?

Comment: "Find all the 'dates' of the match for that user"

"Find the 2nd match (id, 'date') for that user" etc

Comment: @PresidentCamacho Hi! I think the schema created by Dharmesh Patel is exactly how my data look like. I have added it to 'Illustrated by Dharmesh Patel'.

Comment: where are `b_profile_match_status` and `a_profile_match_status` and `created_on` in your given table structure? Please provide right table structure with sample data and desire output with data. It will help you to get better and quick answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Part 1** you can try following query:

```
SELECT * FROM profile_match
WHERE (a_profile_id = 1 AND a_profile_match_available_on is not null)
    OR (b_profile_id = 1 AND b_profile_match_available_on is not null)
ORDER BY (case when a_profile_id=1 
    THEN a_profile_match_available_on 
    ELSE b_profile_match_available_on end
) asc limit 1,1;
```

check following [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de87d/4)

**UPDATE**

check following [modified queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de87d/35):

**PART 1**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT P1.* FROM 
    (SELECT 
        a_profile_id AS profile_id, 
        a_profile_match_available_on as profile_match_available_on 
    FROM profile_match 
    UNION SELECT 
        b_profile_id  AS profile_id, 
        b_profile_match_available_on as profile_match_available_on 
    FROM profile_match) AS P1
) AS P2
GROUP BY P2.profile_id
HAVING P2.profile_id=1 AND 
    profile_match_available_on > MIN(profile_match_available_on);
```

**PART 2**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT P1.* FROM 
    (SELECT 
        a_profile_id AS profile_id, 
        a_profile_match_available_on as profile_match_available_on 
    FROM profile_match 
    UNION SELECT 
        b_profile_id  AS profile_id, 
        b_profile_match_available_on as profile_match_available_on 
    FROM profile_match) AS P1
) AS P2
GROUP BY P2.profile_id
HAVING profile_match_available_on > MIN(profile_match_available_on);
```

Comment: Thanks man. It works perfectly for finding a particular user :). Is there a way to change the '1' in your query such that I can use this query on all the users?

Comment: Thanks! :) Took me quite sometime to understand your query.